# Ableton Can I make the "Session Record Button" start MIDI recording from somewhere in the track I manually select?

Tags: ableton-live

Is there a way to record digital keyboard (midi) into a long midi clip but have the recorder start running from an offsetted position.. Eg. Near the end of the track so I'm not wasting so much time playing it from the start using the default "Session Record Button" feature?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.. you just use the mouse on the timeline to advance where you need to go. Can be done either before or after pressing record!